# Use a variable in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, mvvm

I have a simple problem that I am sure someone can help me with. How can I use my `accountID` variable in the `INavigationAware` methods and then use them in another class?

Below is my code:

ViewModel Relevant Code (HistoryAuditLogViewModel.cs):

```
#region Private Fields

private DatabaseConnectionSetting dbSetting;
private string tableName = "Manufacturers";
private int primaryKeyID = 1;
private string entryID;
private string manufacturerID;
private string manufacturerName;
private string auditDate;
private string sqlLogin;
private string application;
private List<string> dataList;
private string dbConnectionKey = Alliance.Infrastructure.Common.DatabaseConnectionSetting.BACKFLOW_SCOPE_KEY;
private int ShowAuditLogForPrimaryID { get; set; }
private int initialAuditID;
private int _accountID;

private string xmlString()
{
    return "<row EntryID=\"" + entryID + "\" ManufacturerID=\"" + manufacturerID + "\" ManufacturerName=\"" + manufacturerName + "\" AuditDate=\"" + auditDate + "\"  SqlLogin=\"" + sqlLogin + "\" Application=\"" + application + "\" />";
}

private DataSet _dataSet;

#endregion

#region Public Fields

public DataSet dataSet
{
    get { return _dataSet; }
    set { _dataSet = value; }
}

public int accountID
{
    get { return _accountID; }
    set { _accountID = value; }
}

#endregion

#region INavigationAware Members

        bool INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            string tableName;
            string holdStringValue;

            holdStringValue = navigationContext.Parameters["primarykey"];
            if (holdStringValue == null ||
                !Int32.TryParse(holdStringValue, out accountID))
            {
                accountID = 0;
            }

            if (accountID == this.ShowAuditLogForPrimaryID)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
        }

        void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            string holdStringValue;
            int accountID;
            initialAuditID = 0;

            holdStringValue = navigationContext.Parameters["TableName"];
            if (holdStringValue == null ||
                !Int32.TryParse(holdStringValue, out initialAuditID))
            {
                initialAuditID = 0;
            }

            holdStringValue = navigationContext.Parameters["AccountID"];
            if (holdStringValue != null &&
                Int32.TryParse(holdStringValue, out accountID))
            {
                this.ShowAuditLogForPrimaryID = accountID;
            }
            else
            {
                this.ShowAuditLogForPrimaryID = 0;
            }

            Load_Audit();
        }

        #endregion INavigationAware Members
```

I am going to need to use the `accountID` and the table name that is set in those methods. At least I think that is where they are being set.. I have never used `INavigation` so I am a bit confused on how it works.

Here is where I need to be able to use the variable from the ViewModel (CoreModuleDesktop):

```
 this.NavManager.RegisterCommonActionItem("History Audit Log", "AuditLog", 110,
               new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Core;component/Resources/maintenance.png")),
                   new Action(() => 
                    {
                        IRegionManager regionManager = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IRegionManager>();
                        UriQuery query = new UriQuery();

                        query.Add("AccountID", accountID.ToString());
                        //query.Add("ServiceOrderID", tableName.ToString());

                        regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, new Uri(typeof(HistoryAuditLogView).FullName + query.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
                        }));
                  }
```

Basically what this is going to allow me to do is run a query in the ViewModel that places the results of the query in a data grid view. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "Relevant code" is not relevant. What are the variables "accountID" and "the table name"? Are they global variables? The code you post from "CoreModuleDesktop" has NO CONTEXT to it whatsoever. Is it in the same class? Different class? different project? You also forgot to ask a question. Please reformat your post to be more concise and clear about what you're trying to do and what you're having trouble doing.

Comment: I apologize. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O_o Ok, my answer was deleted by an admin. I'm not sure why, but I think I'm getting your problem now. Please look below.

```
public interface ITest 
{
  void Test(string testInput);
}

public class TestImpl : ITest
{
  public int TestId { get; private set; }

  void ITest.Test(string testInput)
  {
    int intOut; //I think this is your point of confusion, right?
    if (!int.TryParse(testInput, out intOut))
      return;

    TestId = intOut; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: It was removed likely because it was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ah chance to improve the post would have been great. At least, I tried to help the TO, but well rough rules here... I'll consider that for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You've already defined a public getter and setter for your `accountID`. You should be able to access the variable by creating an instance of your `HistoryAuditLogViewModel` class.

I should mention -- again -- that your question is really poorly formatted. When I made a comment about relevant code, I didn't mean that you should just post the entire class. You need to find the specific pain points of the code. You already mentioned that you haven't used INavigation before. If you're going to be putting code into your program, you need to understand what it is and how it works.

**What have you tried??** Are you running in to any particular errors? I don't see that you've attempted the problem yourself here -- it's very difficult for us to understand what you're trying to accomplish here, and therefore very difficult to answer your question with any degree of helpfulness.

Comment: The only error I get is that accountID is not used in the current context. I think the problem is that I do not understand how INavigationAware works, because I shouldn't need to declare accountID as a public property or even in the global scope of my ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Same as DNH, don't really get the issue.

But perhaps that your problem is more "how to gain access to my viewmodel instance ?"

In this case you can use the Messaging pattern of MVVM, create a singleton instance which will store the value for the whole app or use static properties.

IMO, messaging or a singleton "repository" are the more appropriate choices here if you don't have any ref to your viewmodel instance.

Comment: What exactly is messaging or a singleton repository?

Comment: Messaging is a basic pattern implemented by some MVVM framework which allow you to subscribe to some types of messages and send messages. http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/ and http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/ implement one.

Comment: For the repository it's a basic pattern too which allow you to store data, validate them, avoid duplication, etc, etc. http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/ But i've mention the term repository with " ' " ;p